# Xmarin.Form iOS Project Building For IPA

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, apple-developer

How can I create **IPA** file from Xamarin.Form iOS project using **Free Provisioning** ?

Note : iOS project work at iPhoneSimulator but when i try to compile for IPA I got

> No installed provisioning profiles match the installed iOS signing
> identities

error. On the MAC host I follow the Free Provisioning guide  [Xmarin Free Provisioning](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/free-provisioning/)  but failed.After getting AppleId I can not create simple XCode app since I got error.

> Failed to create provisioning profile. There are no devices registered
> in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device
> to have Xcode register it.

Apple does not allow me to do anything without purchasing Apple Developer account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no 'legal' ways of creating .ipa files with free provisioning.

However, you can debug on real devices using free provisioning.

[Xamarin Free Provisioning Guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/free-provisioning/) explain it in easy step by step manner. Regarding your issue with AppleID - error message says that you need to connect a device, that's a requirement for free provisioning.

Comment: Thanks. So is there a way  to create .ipa file without connecting a real device(iPhone)?( for example, with buying Apple Developer Account) or in order to create an adhoc ipa file, there must be always a connected real iPhone device?

Comment: @HippiasMinor yes, you can create .ipa file with Apple Developer Account, without connecting a real device. But you need to have all UUID of devices, on which you would like to install that .ipa file. If you want to install that .ipa on any device, you need to buy an Enterprise program, which costs more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So where to put those UUIDs. I buy the developer account but still  got the error "
No installed provisioning profiles match the installed iOS signing identities. " You know any complete tutorial for ipa generetaion?

Comment: Apple just makes things harder

Comment: @HippiasMinor not a particular one, try to find them on youtube. As I find out, that most of the time works better than written ones.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion